# Weird ip addresses in ssh login history

Tags: ssh, ip-address

The following piece of record is among the list from 'last' command:

`root   pts/0   60-249-115-**.hi   Thu Aug  2  00:24 - 02:39  (02:14)`

where ' ** ' stands for two numbers ( I don't know if there is any confidentiality associated with it ) . This part shown under ip section 60-249-115-**.hi looks weird and I don't know if it is an ip address or something else, or even my system is infiltrated. Actually there are several instances of this type which happen about once a few days and the concrete numbers differ from time to time.

Comment: It's a truncated hostname, not an ip address. Numbers in ip addresses are separated by dots.

Answer (score 0):

```
root   pts/0   60-249-115-**.hi   Thu Aug  2  00:24 - 02:39  (02:14)
```

`60-249-115-**.hi` is the first part of a hostname. The software that created the record started with the IP address of the client which made the connection, looked up the hostname associated with the address, and stored the result. These records are stored in a format which doesn't have a lot of space for the remote host, so it's commonly truncated like you see here.

However, in this particular case the four numbers in the hostname also appear to represent the remote IP address. This is because the ISP who controls those IP addresses has chosen to create hostname records which are named after the corresponding IP addresses. This is a common practice.

For example, using a made-up fourth number:

```
$ dig -x 60.249.115.100
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
100.115.249.60.in-addr.arpa. 43200 IN   PTR 60-249-115-100.HINET-IP.hinet.net.
...
```

Here you can see that the hostname associated with "60.249.115.100" is "60-249-115-100.HINET-IP.hinet.net", which is in line with the record in your question.